# Split para separar parte de uma string considera primeiro separador

Tags: c#, string

Tenho o seguinte texto:

> _2910_0908_401 _600_ERV__P_119552_GUARITA ERV SEM ENERGIA RADIO INOPERAN_TE SEMAFOROS P TRENS E VEICLS APAGADOS_PSG TREM C SINAL DE BANDEIRA PELA GUAR_ITA

aí uso o `Split` para quebrar a cada "_"

```
  itens = this.EntidadeMacro.Texto.Split('_');
```

Tem alguma maneira de eu ignorar o primeiro "_" e começar a ir à partir do segundo.

Exemplo: Meu código está fazendo o seguinte:

```
_
2910
```

e deixando esta posição vazia.

e o que preciso e estou tentando achar uma forma de fazer e quebrar à partir do 2º "_":

```
_2910
0908
401
```

e assim sucessivamente ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi é garantido que o primeiro caractere é "_", então basta tratar a exceção da primeira parte. Pode fazer isto:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        string texto = "_2910_0908_401 _600_ERV__P_119552_GUARITA ERV SEM ENERGIA RADIO INOPERAN_TE SEMAFOROS P TRENS E VEICLS APAGADOS_PSG TREM C SINAL DE BANDEIRA PELA GUAR_ITA";
        string[] partes = texto.Substring(1).Split('_');
        partes[0] = "_" + partes[0];
        foreach(string parte in partes) WriteLine(parte);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fZ1m6I). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dNfZkp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Split.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar LINQ?
Se pode, isso funcionou para mim:

```
        Console.Clear();
        string teste = "_2910_0908_401 _600_ERV__P_119552_GUARITA ERV SEM ENERGIA RADIO INOPERAN_TE SEMAFOROS P TRENS E VEICLS APAGADOS_PSG TREM C SINAL DE BANDEIRA PELA GUAR_ITA";
        foreach(string t in teste.Split('_').Where(x => x != ""))
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Entendi, não posso usar LINQ !

Comment: @user2254936 E porque não pode usar LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

Basta ser criativo com o código ;)

```
string foo = "_2910_0908_401 _600_ERV__P_119552_GUARITA ERV SEM ENERGIA RADIO INOPERAN_TE SEMAFOROS P TRENS E VEICLS APAGADOS_PSG TREM C SINAL DE BANDEIRA PELA GUAR_ITA";

int indiceDoPrimeiroUnderline = foo.IndexOf("_");
string primeiraParte = foo.Substring(0, (indiceDoPrimeiroUnderline + 1));
string resto = foo.Substring(indiceDoPrimeiroUnderline + 1);

string[] quebra = resto.Split(new char[] { '_' });
quebra[0] = primeiraParte + quebra[0];
```

O Array `quebra` vai conter todas as partes da string quebrada pelo caractere `_`... Mas o primeiro elemento vai ser diferente, como se o primeiro `_` não tivesse sido considerado para a quebra. Boa sorte!