# Como faço pra receber um valor pra cada variável double no console?

Tags: c#, .net, console

Eu estava fazendo um código bem simples e não queria digitar um número e depois entrar com ele e então entrar com outro número em outra linha, eu queria saber se posso fazer na mesma.

```
        Console.WriteLine("informe o comprimento e a largura da area em metros");

        comprimento = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        largura = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        area = largura * comprimento;

        Console.WriteLine("A area é de" + area+ "m²");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Desse jeito eu tenho que digitar os valores em linhas diferentes, como faço pra digitar na mesma linha ?

Comment: Isto te ajudaria? [C# - Usando Array de argumentos](http://www.macoratti.net/13/10/c_params.htm) ou esta pergunta: [Como ler tres valores na mesma linha? C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282105/como-ler-tres-valores-na-mesma-linha-c)

Comment: vc pode digitar todos os valores sepados por vírgula e depois fazer o `Split`. tem varios exemplos aqui no site, como esse: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38521/57220

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diretamente você não consegue fazer isto com a infraestrutura que o .NET fornece. Ou tem que acessar o console diretamente pela API do sistema operacional, o que é bem complicado, ou tem que recorrer à truques (por exemplo *parsear* o que foi digitado, mas a pessoa tem que digitar certinho e muita coisa pode dar errada, não faça isto).

Melhor ainda, pode fazer o certo e não colocar essa exigência em seu software, ela é ruim do ponto de vista de UX, o correto é pedir os dados de forma separada, inclusive pedir o texto um de cada vez, deste jeito está pedindo para algo dar errado. E parece que não está preocupado com erros porque essa conversão potencialmente quebrará a aplicação, não é assim que é feito. Algo assim é mais correto:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Informe o comprimento em metros: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var comprimento)) return;
        Write("Informe a largura em metros: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var largura)) return;
        WriteLine($"A area é de {largura * comprimento} m²");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nCZmak). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SqvqnI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/InputLine.cs).

Mandei encerrar se o dado não for válido, mas poderia dar uma mensagem de erro, pedir de novo, ou fazer o que achar melhor. Se for pelo caminho de tentar interpretar dois dados em uma linha só muita coisa pode dar errada e seu código seria muito complexo para lidar com todos casos, então faça o simples, inclusive porque ele é mais amigável para o usuário.

Comment: Caso o `TryParse` retorne `false`, `largura` será nula ou deixará de ser declarada? De qualquer forma, na linha seguinte irá causar um erro se não tiver a condição `if(!(largura is null)) ... ;`

Comment: Nem uma coisa nem outra, ela passa ter o valor *default*, no caso 0, mas é importante que você não use esse valor  em caso de falso.

Comment: Se o usuário informar zero, como distinguir se foi entendido corretamente ou se foi atribuído o valor padrão da variável?

Comment: Não é pra distinguir nada, se a pessoa digitou 0 é um valor válido e pode usar, se a pessoa digitou algo errado, a variável tem valor 0, mas vou repetir, não é para usar esse valor. Você acabou de receber um falso indicando que o valor não é válido, porque você o usaria? Já teve sua indicação que não é para usar. É o que tem no C#, fora isso pode criar um mecanismo do [`Option`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/308211/389) e fazer seu próprio `TryParse()` que o retorne.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] dados = null;
        double area = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("informe o comprimento e a largura da area em metros");//o usuario digita SOMENTE os valores EX: 4 4

        dados = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');//usa o split para cortar a string e atribuir os valores na array

        area = double.Parse(dados[0]) * double.Parse(dados[1]); //converte, calcula e atribui 

        Console.WriteLine("A area é de " + area + " m²");`insira o código aqui`
```